# Add Dynamic custom variable in logging Formatter Django Python

Tags: python, django, logging, formatter, django-logging

Let the Following be the logging formatter in settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

Now Say I have three files namely A.py, B.py & C.py

In A.py I have a decorator

```
def myDecorator():
    #Code to generate unique Id for each request in Django APP
    uniqueId = #something
```

In B.py & C.py i have many functions to handle various requests

```
import A.py import myDecorator
import logging

@myDecorator
def func1():
    #Some Code
    logger.debug("Logger message")

@myDecorator
def func2():
    #Some Code
    logger.info("Logger message")

@myDecorator
def func3():
    #Some Code
    logger.debug("Logger message")

def func4():
    #May be Some functions without logger too !!!!
    logger.debug("Logger message")
```

Now I want to log the generated unique Id along with the logger message without being passed explicitly every time in the logger & I also want to make it generic !

Is there by any way I can pass these unique ID's to loggers without passing it explicitly.

```
 'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d 
            %thread)d %(message)s''%(unique_id)s'
    },
},
```

Whenever logger is trigger it should get its corresponding ID from the decorator & log it in **%(unique_id)s** or by default it should log **None**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is typically done is by defining a custom Formatter and injecting your data, in your case the ID, into the log format by accessing the current request.

Comment: Ya I've written a **CustomFormatter** in **settings.py**. But the ID I'm generating is in different file !
Every request now runs in different thread in the host !
So how will I inject the ID generated in Decorators into the Formattor with the help of the Threads ??
Is it possible ??